# Facebook graph - empty variables

Tags: php, facebook, graph

i want to get some info about facebook user on my page, but when i try to do it - it just returns empty strings, my code:

```
  $request = new FacebookRequest( $session, 'GET', '/me' );
  $response = $request->execute();
  // get response
  $graphObject = $response->getGraphObject();
        $fbid = $graphObject->getProperty('id');              // To Get Facebook ID
        $fbfullname = $graphObject->getProperty('name'); // To Get Facebook full name
        $femail = $graphObject->getProperty('email');    // To Get Facebook email ID
        $flocation = $graphObject->getProperty('location');
    /* ---- Session Variables -----*/
        $_SESSION['FBID'] = $fbid;           
        $_SESSION['FULLNAME'] = $fbfullname;
        $_SESSION['EMAIL'] =  $femail;
        $_SESSION['location'] =  $flocation;
    /* ---- header location after session ----*/
```

But it looks like:
[Facebook empty info](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QdYjQ.png)

It returns some strings, but last one is empty...

Comment: During asking permission from your app, if user did not give you permission to access his email ID then it will return empty . (probably its a possibility for this ... right now)

Comment: How can i acess that?

Comment: if user did not give you permission then you can not .... but if its return empty then show a message to a user that you for accessing this app you need to give me your email id .(possible way)

Comment: I know, but how can i ask for more permissions?

Comment: 1 . just loop ... you will not logged in user until user gives you email id redirect him to login page .
2 . Or you can logged user then asking for email id and then you verified those email id .